# Remarks are not italicized while using amsthm package

Tags: pdftex, amsthm

I am using the following code but the Remarks are not italicized while using amsthm package

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

%\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4 paper

\makeatletter
%\let\IEEEproof\proof
%\let\IEEEendproof\endproof
%\let\proof\@undefined
%\let\endproof\@undefined
\let\NAT@parse\undefined
\makeatother

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode, dsfont, color, soul, tikz, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, bbm, bbold, fixmath, mathtools, multirow, boldline, xcolor, colortbl, url, footnote, cite}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = green %Colour of citations
}
%\setlength{\topsep}{3pt}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
%%\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
%\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
%\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]
%\theoremstyle{remark}
%\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

\setlength{\topsep}{3pt}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem*{proof*}{Proof}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{algo}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem*{remark*}{Remark}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only needed if

% you want to use the \thanks command

\overrideIEEEmargins                                      % Needed


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{remark}
 My remark ...
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a consequence of the preceding `\theoremstyle{remark}`. If you want remarks italicized, I think you need to move their `\newtheorem` declarations up above the `\theoremstyle{definition}` line.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks. It worked :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. I had posted it as a comment rather than an answer because of lack of time to do a proper job of it. I have now expanded it into a proper answer (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a consequence of the preceding `\theoremstyle{remark}`. If you want remarks italicized,  you need to move their `\newtheorem` declarations up above the `\theoremstyle{definition}` line. To quote the documentation explaining what the different theorem styles look like:

- `plain` : italic text, extra space above and below; (this is the default)
- `definition` : upright text, extra space above and below;
- `remark` : upright text, no extra space above or below.

It may be worth noting that the package also provides a `\newtheoremstyle` command that you can use if the above styles don't suffice for your needs. For example, if you want remarks in italic but without the extra spacing provided by the `plain` style.